# «от самого себя» vs «от себя самого»

Tags: порядок-слов

In conversation, I just said:

> Разве терять голову и быть в восторге от **самого себя** – это как раз не значит поступить не по-взрослому?

Sometimes I find myself of two minds about the position of "сам" when it is  placed right next to "себя". In terms of emphasis and style, how does my phrasing compare with:

> Разве терять голову и быть в восторге от **себя самого** – это как раз не значит поступить не по-взрослому?

Comment: **себя самого** seems to elevate the register, in speech their order may get reversed when the speaker misses **самого** and adds it post factum, which is likely because it's only secondary to **себя**

Comment: That's true that in speaking we can use it both ways. For me it is easier to pronounce the first sentence, rhythmically and articulatory.

Answer (score 1):

In the Russian language there is an idiom **"себя любимого"** (**"beloved myself"** / **"beloved himself"**). Examples:

> Как же я при выборе кандидата на должность главы комиссии забуду себя любимого?
>   Ты весь вечер говоришь только о себе любимом!

If you are talking about any narcissistic aspects, it makes sense to say **"себя самого"**, because this order of words is a reference to the phrase **"себя любимого"**.

**"Самого себя"** on the contrary is associated with the standard Russian phrase **"От самого себя не убежишь"** (**"You can not escape from yourself"**) and has a certain fatalistic connotation. Therefore, in this case, this word order is less appropriate.

Comment: От себя не убежишь. You can put самого anywhere here, but it is not necessary. Usually it is without самого.

Comment: @Elena, **"От себя самого не убежишь"** is used very rarely. Usually only in situations when the author consciously wants to go beyond the standard use of this phrase. In most cases **"самого"** is either placed before **"себя"** or not placed at all.